# dynamic stylesheet with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have and angularjs application that fetches data via api, and builds a webpage with it.

Usually I use ng-style to create dynamic styling, but now I have to use the nth-of-type attribute that can only be used in a css stylesheet (I cannot use individual styling since the number and order of elements always change).

I have tried this naive code (in the html page):

```
<style ng-if="styles.sc && styles.sc.length==3">
    a.mosection:nth-of-type(3n) > div {
        background-color: {{styles.sc[0]}} !important;
    }
    a.mosection:nth-of-type(3n+1) > div {
        background-color: {{styles.sc[1]}} !important;
    }
    a.mosection:nth-of-type(3n+2) > div {
        background-color: {{styles.sc[2]}} !important;
    }
</style>
```

But it didn't work... Apparently angular doesn't bind the data inside the style tag (the ng-if attribute does get digested properly)

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should checkout those three ng-*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven

all of them can accept functions as attributes, you can also checkout 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

which might be actually the best in your case

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
I indeed solved it by using ng-style with a function

The HTML

```
<div class="widget widget-people" ng-style="{backgroundColor: staggerBgColors('widget', 'widget-people', '#333333')}"></div>
<div class="widget widget-property" ng-style="{backgroundColor: staggerBgColors('widget', 'widget-property', '#24d10f')}"></div>
```

The scope function

```
$scope.staggerBgColors = function(elesClass, eleClass, defaultColor){
  if (!$scope.styles || !$scope.styles.sc || $scope.styles.sc.length!=3){
    return defaultColor;
  }else{
    var listItem = $('.'+eleClass);
    var n = $('.'+elesClass).index( listItem ) % 3;
    return '#' + $scope.preview.moment.sc[n];
  }
}
```

I had to implement the same functionality of the css property "nth-of-type" using jQuery, but it works prefectly!